# Is it possible to install pcsc-lite 1.8.13 on raspbian OS?

Tags: raspbian, linux, debian, nfc

I'm working on a raspberry pi project. I'm trying to install a [driver package](http://www.acs.com.hk/download-driver-unified/5128/ACS-Unified-PKG-Lnx-110-P.zip) for ACR1251U-A1 NFC tag.

This package requires to install pcsc-lite package at first. But as I understand after a search on the internet, pcsc-lite 1.8.13 is not possible for raspbian OS.

But my supervisor persists that pcsc-lite 1.8.13 should be installed on raspberry pi to make nfc tag work.

Is it possible to install it on raspbian? If it is so, could you help me how to do that?

Comment: Hello and welcome! What do you mean by "is not possible for raspbian"? Is there no package provided or is it not possible to install/run it for whatever reason? If it is just no package, could it be installed from source?

Comment: Ghanima, when I try to install with the command apt-get install libpcsc1 1.8.13, the raspberry pi automatically installs me an earlier version 1.8.4-1+deb7u1. And the problem is, my supervisor persists that, the nfc reader doesn't work because this version is wrong version for nfc-reader and raspberry pi suitability. I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: Could the correct version be installed from source? Or could `apt-get` not be forced to install a specific version only? (Sorry I am not into `apt-get` so I cannot tell.)

Comment: well, I have tried to download libpcsc1 1.8.13 from repository, but the problem is I couldn't install it. I think there is no specific installation in raspbian for libpcsc1 1.8.13. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Assuming that you ran sudo apt-get update before installing, your only option may be to install from source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to install `pcscd` daemon and using `pcsc-lite` [wrapper in NodeJS](https://github.com/santigimeno/node-pcsclite) on Raspbian (`Linux raspberrypi 3.18.11-v7+ #781 SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 21 18:07:59 BST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux`) using Raspberry Pi B+ and Raspberry Pi 2.

Here an extract of the *Requirements installation* from the [full guide of mine project on GitHub](https://github.com/goodotcom/rfid-reader-http):

> 2. Install PC/SC and libnfc (references: [nfc-tools](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Libnfc#Debian_.2F_Ubuntu), [libnfc](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc)):
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install pcscd libusb-dev libpcsclite1 libpcsclite-dev dh-autoreconf
>
>    cd /opt/
>    sudo wget https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/archive/libnfc-1.7.1.zip
>    sudo unzip libnfc-1.7.1.zip
>    cd libnfc-libnfc-1.7.1/
>    sudo autoreconf -vis
>    sudo ./configure --with-drivers=all
>    sudo make
>    sudo make install
>    ```
>
>    Additionaly, you may need to grant permissions to your user to drive the device.
>      Under GNU/Linux systems, if you use `udev`, you could use the provided `udev` rules.
>          e.g. under Debian: `sudo cp /opt/libnfc-libnfc-1.7.1/contrib/udev/42-pn53x.rules /lib/udev/rules.d/`
> 3. Make sure the NFC reader is properly recognized:
>
>    ```
>    sudo nfc-list
>    ```
>
>    1. To fix: `error while loading shared libraries: libnfc.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` ([reference](http://seckev.blog.com/2013/04/17/installation-mfterm-with-acr122u-on-kali-linux-system/))
>
>       ```
>       echo '/usr/local/lib' | sudo tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/usr-local-lib.conf && sudo ldconfig
>       ```
>    2. If you have kernel version > 3.5, probably `pcscd` and also `nfc-list` will report this error: `Unable to claim USB interface (Device or resource busy)` due to the automatic load of `pn533` driver.
>
>       To read the `pcscd` dameon output you can run it using: `pcscd -f -d`
>
>       1. Check which kernel version is installed: `uname -a`
>       2. Blacklist `pn533` and `nfc` drivers (references: [Arch Linux wiki Touchatag RFID Reader](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchatag_RFID_Reader), [nfc-tools forum](http://forums.nfc-tools.org/post/5308/#p5308)):
>
>          ```
>          sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-libnfc.conf
>          ```
>
>          Add the following lines:
>
>          blacklist pn533
>                blacklist nfc
>       3. Disable kernel modules:
>
>          ```
>          modprobe -r pn533 nfc
>          ```
>       4. Restart the `pcscd` daemon: `sudo service pcscd restart`

Answer (score 1):

The nfc-tools.org website has good directions for [how to install on ubuntu systems](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Libnfc#Debian_.2F_Ubuntu).

Here is how I did it on my Raspberry Pi 3 B running Raspbian 8.0 (jessie)

```
sudo apt-get install pcscd libusb-dev libpcsclite1 libpcsclite-dev dh-autoreconf libudev-dev libusb-0.1-4
sudo wget -O /lib/udev/rules.d/93-pn53x.rules https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/master/contrib/udev/93-pn53x.rules

cd ~
git clone https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc.git
cd libnfc
git checkout libnfc-1.7.1
git clean -d -f -x
rm ../libnfc*.deb #may not exist
git remote|grep -q anonscm||git remote add anonscm git://anonscm.debian.org/collab-maint/libnfc.git
git fetch anonscm
git checkout remotes/anonscm/master debian
git reset
dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -b
sudo dpkg -i ../libnfc*.deb
```

Next plug in NFC device, wait 30 seconds. May have to unplug then plug in again.  Now you can run `nfc-list` to see if your device is detected.

If you are still running into problems stop the pcsc daemon (`sudo service pcscd stop`) then manually run `sudo pcscd -f -d` to monitor the output.

**Note**: You will have to restart `pcscd` and unplug and re-plug your device to use it over pcsc after running `nfc-list`