# omnikey 5421 contactless driver for Raspberry pi

Tags: driver

I am new to Raspberry Pi and I want to use an [HID Omnikey 5421](https://www.hidglobal.com/products/readers/omnikey/5421) with a Raspberry Pi - it is a dual interface contact and contactless reader. After some research I was able to communicate with the contact reader using [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29892/is-it-possible-to-install-pcsc-lite-1-8-13-on-raspbian-os), but the contactless reader is not visible in Raspberry Pi. It seems like some driver problem. Can any one help me with this?

Comment: I believe the *driver problem* here is that official drivers are closed-source and only exist for x86 platform. I may be wrong (and I hope I am), but it looks like you bought two incompatible pieces of hardware which you want to work together, completely ignoring the word *incompatible*.

Answer (score 3):

## Buy A Compatible Card Reader

You're probably going to have to buy a card reader that is compatible with the Raspberry Pi.

---

### Elaborating on Dmitry's Comment

Basically, drivers need to be compatible with both your [**OS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) and your [**CPU**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit).

You're likely running [*Raspbian*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspbian) as your OS, which is a [*Linux*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) distribution.

The Raspberry Pi v1 has an [*ARM6*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM6) CPU, while Raspberry Pi v2 and v3 have [*ARM7*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM7) CPUs.

So you'll need drivers for Linux ARM6 or Linux ARM7.

---

The only Linux drivers available on HID Global's [Drivers & Downloads](https://www.hidglobal.com/drivers) page are for devices with *[i686](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/i686)* or *[x86_64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)* CPUs, so those drivers aren't compatible with any of the Raspberry Pi's.

While it's sometimes possible to use an emulator program (like [QEMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU)) to run i686 applications on ARM, emulating i686 drivers can be [complicated](https://www.lhinderberger.de/pi/2016/01/27/raspberry-pi-binary-x86-drivers.html).

---

The only drivers available for ARM6 or ARM7 are for the [Windows CE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_CE) OS:

> OMNIKEY 5x2x PC/SC driver for Windows CE
>
> ...for Windows CE.NET 7.0 for ARM5, ARM6, ARM7...

While it's possible to run some Windows applications on Linux using the [wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29) compatibility layer, support for Windows CE is very limited, and you [shouldn't expect any success](https://wiki.winehq.org/ARM#Running_Windows_CE_Applications).

Answer (score 0):

I have also been struggling with this same issue, and had a stroke of good fortune with timing!

HID have now released a driver for their Omnikey encoders that is compatible with the ARM processor, and is [available here](https://www.hidglobal.com/drivers/29738).